# Proof explanation strict inequality with sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

Prove that if $2 \lt x_1 \lt 3$ and $x_{n+1} = 2 + \sqrt{x_n-2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $0 \lt x_n \lt x_{n+1}$

Assuming $x \in \mathbb{R}$

clearly $n = 1$

$x_1 \gt 0$ since $x_{n} \gt 2$

$x_{n+1} \gt 2$

So both $x_n$ and $x_{n+1} \gt 0 \space \space \space  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

So now:

$x_n \lt 2 + \sqrt{x_n -2}$

$x_n - 2 \lt \sqrt{x_n - 2}$ $x = x_n - 2$

we have $x_n \lt \sqrt{x} \space \space \space \space \forall x \lt 1$

I don't know how to end the argument for some reason.

Comment: $2<x_n<3\implies 0<x_n-2<1 \implies 0<x_n-2<\sqrt{x_n-2}=x_{n+1}-2\implies 0<x_n<x_{n+1}$

Comment: I meant $\color{red}2<x_n<x_n+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2<x_n<3\implies 0<x_n-2<1 \implies 0<x_n-2<\sqrt{x_n-2}=x_{n+1}-2<1$

$\implies 2<x_n<x_{n+1}<3.$

Therefore $2<x_n<3\implies2<x_{n+1}<3$ and $x_n<x_{n+1}$.

Since $2<x_1<3,$ it follows that, for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ $2<x_{n+1}<3$ and $x_n<x_{n+1}.$

(Note that $0<x_n$ from the definitions of $x_1$ and $x_{n+1}.$)

Comment: my only concern is jumping from $x_1$ to $x_n$

Comment: between 2 and three

Comment: It's an induction argument:  $2<x_1<3$ and $2<x_n<3\implies 2<x_{n+1}<3,$ so $2<x_n<3$ for all $n$

Comment: So could I even write my proof like this: Assume $2 \lt x_n \lt 3$ For base case assume this holds true for $n = 1$. Indeed $ 2 \lt  x_1 \lt 3$ Holds true. Then I do the algebra ans arrive at $2 \lt x_n \lt x_{n+1} \lt 3$ Which concludes it also holds for $n+1$. Which means $0 \lt x_n \lt x_{n+1} 3$ holds true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: To show $2<x_n<3$ for all $n$ by induction, we show that it holds for the base case ($n=1)$ and then we show, assuming $2<x_k<3$, that $2<x_{k+1}<3$

Comment: okay makes perfect sense now

Comment: now it flows fluidly

Answer (score 1):

You can show:  $3 > x_n > 2, \forall n \ge 1$. Lets do this first. We have $3 > x_1 > 2$ ( given ). Assume $x_n > 2 \implies x_{n+1} = 2 + \sqrt{x_n - 2} > 2 + 0 = 2$, and $x_{n+1} < 2+\sqrt{3-2} = 3$ Thus $3 > x_n > 2, \forall n \ge 1$. This means $x_n > 0, \forall n \ge 1$. Next you show $x_n < x_{n+1}$. Indeed, $x_{n+1} - x_n = 2+\sqrt{x_n-2} - x_n= \sqrt{x_n-2}\left(1 - \sqrt{x_n-2}\right)> 0$ since $2 < x_n < 3\implies x_{n+1} > x_n$.

Comment: how can I go from showing $x_1$ to $ 2 \lt x_n \lt 3$

Comment: it doesn't explicitly state $x_n$ is between those numbers